# Рекомендательное удаление сообщений

Tags: предложение, инструменты-модератора

Сейчас сделано так, что если модератор удаляет сообщение, то только модератор может его восстановить. С другой стороны, если сообщение удаляется автором, то автор может единолично его восстанавливать.

Периодически в очередь проверок попадают сообщения, которые могли бы быть дополнены до нормального ответа. В таких случаях обычно приходится писать комментарий и оставлять необработанную тревогу, чтобы потом можно было к ней вернуться.

Но вместо этого было бы удобнее удалить сообщение, но дать автору возможность его исправить и восстановить самостоятельно.

Т. е. я предлагаю предоставить модераторам как минимум два вида удаления:

- окончательное, как есть сейчас
- рекомендательное, при котором автор сможет восстановить сам после правки